# Sending input array with jQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to send a form field array through my form but am unsuccessfull :-/

I have a hidden field, generated from jQuery, looking like this:

```
$(".imghidden").html('<input type="hidden" name="pimage[]"  value="'+data.imgname+'">');
```

This is generated for each file uploaded to this post. When I then submit the form I do not get anything through the "pimage" form submission. All other fields return a value?!? Below is the jQuery Ajax I am trying to use:

```
var $form = $( this ),
    category = $form.find( "select[name='category']" ).val(),
    newcategory = $form.find( "input[name='newcategory']" ).val(),
    title = $form.find( "input[name='title']" ).val(),
    subtitle = $form.find( "input[name='subtitle']" ).val(),
    content = $form.find( "textarea[name='content']" ).val(),
    pimage = $form.find( "input[name='pimage']" ).val()

// Send the data using post
var posting = $.post( "data/mod/projects.php", { createnew: true, cat: category, newcat: newcategory, ti: title, sti: subtitle, con: content, pimg: pimage  });
```

What am I doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Is the `.imghidden` element that you append the hidden element to within the `$form`? If you do `console.log($form.find("input[name='pimage']").length)` what value do you get?

Comment: try $form.find( "input[name^='pimage']" ).val()

Comment: You would have better to serialize the FORM instead of building FORM data manually: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your jQuery selector is looking for an input with name `pimage`... which doesn't exist. I haven't tested it, but it looks like your jQuery selector should be looking for `pimage[]` instead.

e.g.

```
pimage = $form.find( "input[name='pimage[]']" ).val()
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I also found helpful to use the :checked pseudo-selector to get the checked values. E.g.  pimage = $form.find( "input[name='pimage[]']:checked" ); To get an array of checked values: var pimages = $('input[name="pimage[]"]:checked').map(function(){ 
                    return this.value; 
                }).get();

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find a selector that doesn't exist. Try

```
$form.find( "input[name^='pimage']" ).val()
```